# Httpclient redirects android

Tags: android, httpclient

The problem is as following : 
I use **httpclient** to post login data to server.

While using firefox on my desktop with live headers the server redirects me to url2 witk 302, then to url3 with 302 and then I get 200 ok. In android I got the same login page and 200 OK.

Then I disabled automatic redirect handling got the response and saw 302 redirect, BUT

"`String location = response.getHeaders("Location")[0].toString();`" gave me the same login page url and not the one from firefox.

I have no idea why is that.

Code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri[0]);
HttpResponse response;
String responseString = null;

HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

// Adding namvalue pairs here - adding correct i'm sure

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){                    
       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
       out.close();
       responseString = out.toString();
} else{
       if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY)
       {
          String location = response.getHeaders("Location")[0].toString();

       }
       response.getEntity().getContent().close();     
}
```

Firefox headers:

[image]

**What i get is : location= /login/**

Comment: can you add up stack traces and your code.

Comment: Added some code, don't know about stack traces as there's no error